# Need help plotting analytical solution of phytoplankton resource competition model in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a one species, two resources phytoplankton competition model based on Tilman's work in the 70s and 80s. I have a dataframe set up for the analytical solution but am really struggling with the syntax to plot the graphs I need. Here is my code so far:

```
library(dplyr)

r <- 0.1
g1 <- 0.001
g2 <- 0.01
v1 <- 0.1
v2 <- 1
k1 <- 0.01
k2 <- 0.1
d <- 0.15

s1_star = (r*g1*k1*d)-((v1*(r-d))-r*g1*d)
s2_star = (r*g2*k2*d)-((v2*(r-d))-r*g2*d)
s01 = s1_star+((s02-s2_star)*(g1/g2))

params <- list(r = 0.1, 
               g1 = 0.001,
               g2 = 0.01,
               d = 0.5,
               v1 = 0.1,
               v2 = 1,
               k1 = 0.01,
               k2 = 0.1)


df <- data.frame(s02 = seq(10, 1, -1)) |>
  mutate(
    s1_star = (r*g1*k1*d)-((v1*(r-d))-r*g1*d),
    s2_star = (r*g2*k2*d)-((v2*(r-d))-r*g2*d),
    s01 = s1_star+((s02-s2_star)*(g1/g2)), ## Tilman eq 17, supply concentration of resource 1
    ## in the reservoir that would result in co-limitation given some concentration of 
    ## resource 2 (s20) in the reservoir
    s1_limiting_ratio = s02/s01  ## ratio of supply points that result in co-limitation
  )

cbind(params, df) |> as.data.frame() -> limiting_ratio

library(ggplot2)

limiting_ratio |> ggplot(aes(x = s1_star, y = s2_star)) + geom_line()
```

I want to plot s1_star and s2_star as the axes (which I did), but I'm trying to add the s1_limiting_ratio as a line on the graph (it's a ratio of s02/s01, which represents when resource 1 (S1) and resource 2 (S2) are co-limited. Then, I want to plot various values of s01 and s02 on the graph to see where they fall (to determine which resource is limiting to know which resource equation to use, either S1 or S2, in the analytical solution.

I've tried googling ggplot help, and struggling to apply it to the graph I need. I'm still fairly new to R and definitely pretty new to ggplot, so I really appreciate any help and advice!

Comment: When I run your code, the values for `s1_star` and `s2_star` are all the same in the data frame, so there is no line to plot.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch (or plot in Excel?) of what you want the plot to look like? It's hard to understand the plot that you're aiming for from the description.